# React Native [rendered more hooks than during the previous render]

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, async-await, hook

I am using a custom hook that takes result from an async function and set state and return it, but some time i get error message that "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" I have checked my code multiple times and checked if and else conditions as per suggested on multiple articles but still error persist and not sure why its coming. below is my code snippet to be checked.

```
function T(key: string, x?: any) {
const [state, setState] = useState(key);
  useEffect(() => {
    const doTranslation = async () => {
      try {
        const lang = await getSelectedLanguage();
        let translatedValue = await TranslizedModule.translate(key, lang);
        if (translatedValue === undefined || translatedValue === "") translatedValue = key;
        setState(translatedValue);
      } catch (error) {
        setState(key);
      }
    };

    doTranslation();
  }, [key, x]);

  return state;
}
```

Many Thanks